# How to protect SQL Server from Hackers

Tags: sql-server, firewall

I am having an issue and could not figure out how to handle it.

I have an SQL Server on a Windows 2008 RC2 server. This SQL Server 2005 is being used to receive DB subscriptions from another SQL Server located elsewhere on the Internet.

I have the SQL Server port open through the firewall, however in the scope, I have entered the IP of the other SQL Server. Doing so I hoped that connection requests through that port will not reach the SQL Server unless the requests are coming from the other SQL Server (whose IP is listed in the scope in the firewall rule). But, when I see the log, there are hundreds of  entries (and they are coming each passing second).

> login failed user sa

It appears some hacker is trying brute force to guess user `sa` password.  But the question is, why Windows is letting these request reach the SQL Server even though they are not coming from the IP address that is listed in the firewall scope? What is the right way to protect this SQL Server?

No other IP than the IP of the other SQL Server needs to connect to this SQL Server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SQL server administration.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site.  Where do I post questions related to SQL Server?

Comment: @AllenKing you can post this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ you will get a quicker answer, very interesting question though.

Comment: Thanks. I am already learning a lot just by communicating with experts here.

Comment: and please try to format your question so its easier for readers to read it :) and also provide details of what you have tried so far to solve the problem , good luck pal

Comment: @M.Ali - It is a firewall configuration question really so belongs on ServerFault.com. The fact that the process on the other end happens to be a database server is more or less incidental.